# Number of WebSQL databases limited to 1 on a WebView but not in Chrome itself?

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

I am currently developing an application using Cordova, which uses window.openDatabase() to get access to an SQL database.

This works fine on iOS, but on Android it turns out however that whenever I try to open more than one database, the second request throws a DOM Exception 18. The requested size of the database(s) doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
  var db = window.openDatabase("test",1,"test",500); // doesn't throw an Exception
  var db2 = window.openDatabase("test2",1,"test2",500); // throws an Exception
```

I have been reading through the Cordova source code, and searched around, and didn't find anything describing a limitation, except perhaps for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebStorage.html. It explains that there can be only one application cache per application. No explicit limit is mentioned for WebSQL however.

There does seem to be a difference between running inside Chrome and as a WebView, because when running in Chrome there doesn't seem to be a limit, and no exception is being thrown.

Does the limit for ApplicationCache described in the WebStorage class also apply to WebSQL when being used on a (Cordova) Webview, or is this limit created by Cordova itself?

Comment: Phonegap Developer chat : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap-framework

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is indeed a limit of one database. The solution to this problem is to not use the WebView WebSQL storage, but to use an SQLite plugin instead.
The plugin I used is https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

It can be easily installed in cordova using the command line interface:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin
```

This doesn't replace `window.openDatabase`, but will add itself as `navigator.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase`. The API is the same.

This gets rid of the limitation of 1 database per WebView as well as limitations in size per database.